# Adding text to textbox from a list

Tags: forms, wpf

In our application there is a form to specify command line arguments to run an EXE with. We also want to provide some keywords that the user can use, now we put them in a listview. Currently, it looked like this:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLj93.png]

When the user double click on an item in the listview, it will be added to the current caret position in the textbox. The text can really span a few lines, that's why the text box is quite big.

Is there a better way to have this functionality? The problem with current design:

- It looks weird because the listbox is not as wide as the textbox
- It takes a lot of vertical space (listbox + textbox)
- The two controls are quite separated vertically, due to the height of the textbox.

How can this be improved?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way is to use [autocompletion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocomplete). Autocompletion is good because user will be able to insert parameter value instantly (i.e. without leaving text area and switching to other controls, etc):

[image: autocompletion]

Other possible option I see is to use Insert macro button with variants:

[image: combo]

And if there are just a few of items, you may try to place separate button for every macro above or underneath the text area. It may also be used in parallel with the autocompletion:

[image: buttons]

Comment: do you know any example or screenshot of the last approach (list of buttons)?

Comment: @LouisRhys I've updated my answer with the sample wireframe. It's like a toolbar for the text editor.